# Input Window Closing abruptly OpenCV

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv

I want the project to open a window and detect my hand movement to form words. The window is closing abruptly. Please help.

Link to the project:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gQ65Su9Xk-ZCzGSmexOZfMr8662P9TsK?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Add ( & 0xFF )

```
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # press e to terminate the camera
    if k == ord("e"):
        break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This should help.
Make sure to close the braces properly as this new code should be inside the while loop only.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted is a google drive folder with multiple python files. Try to specify which file you are referring to, next time.
I am assuming it is the Untitled notebook. My answer is to just unindent video_capture.release() and cv2.destroyAllWindows().

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this didn't solve the problem. I gave the link for more convenience. I think the error is in WordToWeb.py file.
Thank you.